# Display numbers twice on x axis in excel chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

I have following values that I would like to display on the X axis of my chart:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
```

But my chart is displaying the values as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...

Is there a way to use the values as single entries instead of using them as values?

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently you want to interpret your numbers as a text. Have you tried formatting them as a text (prefixing values with ' or by using [TEXT function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx))?

Comment: I cant, because i need them for some math. I tried to set them as text in the chart with no result.

Comment: @user2452250 What about using TEXT function - http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx ?

Comment: How are these values stored? Are they 1 entry per cell?

Comment: Are you running any macro's/vba on the work sheet

Answer (score 1):

You've not said which version of Excel you're using, but it should be similar for most recent versions I think:

- Choose **Insert -> Charts -> Insert Line Chart -> Line** from the ribbon to insert a blank line graph.
- With the graph selected, click the **Select Data** option from the ribbon
- With the cursor in the **Chart data range** text box, highlight the cells containing your Y values
- On the right-hand side, under *Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels*, click **Edit**
- Select the range containing your X axis values and press **OK**
- Press **OK** to close the chart editor dialog.

[image]